# CSS Disable a tag when i hit a certain resolution

Tags: css

Good Day,

I have HTML code that looks like this:

```
<a href="index.html#timeline-embed" class="btn btn-large" data-scroll="true">Latest</a>
<a href="index.html#timeline-embed" class="btn btn-large" data-scroll="true">TL</a>
```

And Basically, CSS that looks like this:

```
.btn-large
{
  padding: 11px 19px;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Basically, I want it such that when my browser is resized to a certain resolution, .btn-large should not apply/work anymore. How can I do this? How would I do this with an @media query.

Comment: You want it hidden? Or you want to to be displayed just not clickable?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You clearly know what it is you are supposed to use, so you must have seen at least some basic documentation or example using it. Have you tried applying that example to your sitation? If so, [what exactly did you try?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)